# App Forcecloses on opening

Tags: android

Hello everyone I am new to Apps so sorry for this :D

The idea of this app is creating a list with values, choosing a random value thus choosing a list item. You can save the list to a text file. Problem is, my app is forceclosing whenever I open it.I have no idea what is happening but do have a log cat:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frostbytedev.randomgenie/com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Here is my Java:

```
package com.frostbytedev.randomgenie;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button OpenList, NewList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        OpenList=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bOpenList);
        NewList=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bNewList);
        OpenList.setOnClickListener(this);
        NewList.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

and XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".Menu">


    <Button
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New List"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bNewList"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Open a List"
            android:id="@+id/bOpenList"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the XML, set the ID of the first button to @+id/bNewList.  Your onCreate can't find that ID since your first button is set to have the id of "button".

Answer (score 0):

answer above should fix the problem.

but for future reference, the LogCat is great for debugging.

if you double click this line

```
        at com.frostbytedev.randomgenie.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:19)
```

in your LogCat, it will take you to the exact line of code that has the problem, which was a NullPointerException in your onCreate function in your Menu class at line 19.

in other words, NullPointerException means that a value you set was NULL and it cant be NULL.